# Microsoft Windows 11 default Weather app API

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to call default weather app provided by Microsoft from command-line, but I have only found out that you can use just some shortcuts for opening this app, my goal is to set location and find forecast for current day using API similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app). Is there some way how to achieve it with this app, or should I use third party library for example?

I was trying to play with following commands, but they weren't working for me.

`start bingweather://forecast?lo=12.234&ala=45.678`
or
`start bingweather:?q=London`